# desperately need 110v from a 208v pdu

Tags: datacenter, electrical-power, power-distribution-unit

I'm in a bit of a pickle... We're moving a client's infrastructure to a colocation facility.  We have redundant 208v/30amp PDUs.

While installing today, we realized that the client had a small collection of devices (fax modems, etc) that must have a 110v source.

We need to get power to these devices this weekend, and the data center won't be able to provide a separate 110v PDU until next week at the earliest.

Is the a way to build a stepdown converter we could temporarily use?
Is there something else (maybe a UPS?), a special adapter, that would do the job?

Comment: Oh man. Answer: yes. SOMEONE, I am sure, has something like that. No product or service recommendations, sorry.

Comment: so how is the client powering these things now? Can whatever they're doing also be relocated to the colo facility, at least on a temporary basis, or are they doing something that would make a competent electrician wrap themselves in insulation then cry themselves to sleep?

Comment: Grab a used UPS (there are websites for that kind of local demand...) that takes 208v input, or go to a local  decent electrical supplier and pay through the teeth.  Either is easily do-able in a weekend.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need a stepdown converter if what you have is 208V three phase power.  Each phase has a potential of 120v (note that you want 120v, not 110v.  Common mistake) to neutral.   What you would use is something like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008OUL37M), which splits the phases for you.  Some UPSs would do this too. I don't know of any place that would have this for the weekend.  You might be able to find an adapter like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DM87M7G).  If you are really desperate, you can make a 120V plug yourself.  You just have to take one of the three phase wires, the neutral, and the ground and connect it to a 120v NEMA-5 receptacle, found at any hardware store.  Of course, without experience, this could be dangerous, but with proper fear and care, it's doable.

Additional thoughts:  If the colo has an electrician on staff, he/she may be willing to rig something.  Probably not.  If I had a neckbeard or a COBOL programmer on staff he'd be my goto on this.